# Migrate WordPress site that has Google Tag Manager staging environment

Tags: wordpress, google-tag-manager, staging

I have setup a staging environment within GTM and embedded the GTM code snippet on my staging site. When I use something like the Duplicator WP plugin to copy the staging site to live, the staging GTM snippet will naturally get migrated along too. Thus the staging GTM snippet will need to be replaced with the live GTM snippet, each time I migrate.

Is there a better way I should be doing this so that I don't have to replace the snippets every time I migrate or promote code from staging to live?

Comment: I assume you have a WP site. My recommendation is that you migrate all the database table except the table for the GTM plugin.

Comment: @AnthonyG assumed you have a WP site. His recommendation is that you migrate all the database table except the table for the GTM plugin.

Comment: The assumption is I have a WP site. The recommendation is I migrate all the database tables except the table for the GTM. plugin. Except GTM is not a plugin and there is no table for it.